# Gitlab submodule with specific files

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two repositories. One repository needs some files from another. I manage to use the second repository as a submodule in the first.

My question is: It is possible to make a submodule just with some files? Example: A and B are the repositories. B contains files 1,2 and 3. I need to make a submodule just with file 2 from B in A.

Answer (score 2):

1.Clone repository A to your local.  git clone https://github.com/xx/repository B

2.Add repository B as a remote repository in A. git remote add RB https://github.com/xx/repository B

3.git fetch RB

4.git checkout master

5.git merge RB/master --allow-unrelated-histories

6.It will merge all the files 1, 2 ,3 to your local master branch in repository A

7.Remove the files 1 and 2. git rm 1 -f

Comment: I am relatively new to gitlab. So now I will have in repository A a direct connection with the file 2 in B? (if I edit file 2 in A and commit and push it to the server it will make an automatic update also in file 2) I ask this because I need a system that works similar with the submodule system.

Comment: I tested it an apparently not :(